# WCF binding config - server or client

Tags: c#, wcf

So I create NetTcpBinding on both sever and client side (in a runtime), but how will connection behave in case of configuration conflicts? E.g. if on server I have

```
binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
```

and I forget to put same lines on client side, would the reliable session actually be working?

Edit: to rephrase, in case of any binding and any binding property, if they differ on server and client, which one will be used in work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetTcpBinding does not enable a reliable session by default. So although your endpoint supports a reliable session, it will not use a reliable session if it is not used/enabled by the client.

This feature needs to be configured in the configuration files for the client and service if a reliable session is required.

Comment: Thank you, that's important notice. But I mostly need to know how conflicts in cofigurations would be solved by framework

Comment: I don't believe there is a conflict. By enabling reliableSession on your endpoint you are able to initiate a reliable session with clients who have enabled the feature.

Comment: ReliableSession is just an example. What if I have different timeout values, which one will be used?

Comment: I don't think it's very straight forward with a general rule that can be applied to all attributes. Specifically, I believe timeouts will default to whichever times out first. Here is some good information that you should find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879310/when-setting-up-a-wcf-client-and-server-how-synchronized-does-the-config-files